# Knockout template. Passing simple data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to pass in template simple integer.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'TemplateName', data: 1 }">
```

I have knockout template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateName">
    <input type="button" value="val" data-bind="click: $root.stop.bind($data, @@WHAT_IS_IT@@)"/>
</script>
```

I want to get

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateName">
    <input type="button" value="val" data-bind="click: $root.stop.bind($data, 1)"/>
</script>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you tried `$data`? So  `($root.stop.bind($data, $data)`?

Comment: Yes, and template was rendered to `($root.stop.bind($data, $data)`

Comment: And? Is it not working as you expected? here in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/d4n5vL15/ you can see 1 displayed when you click on the button...

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I expected to see `data-bind="click: $root.stop.bind($data, 1)"` in HTML, but it wrong. Code work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, wanting to reuse the same template except for 1 property.
To solve this I created a new template binding, that allows me to extend the model that's currently known with a context model.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.templateWithContext = {
    init: ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        ko.utils.extend(context, options.context);

        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.templateWithContext = true;
```

This allows a new parameter to be added when calling a binding, named 'context'.
In this context parameters you can create an object, and all properties within this object are properties exposed to the template.

I prefer this method over using the 'data' parameter, because this extends the $data model, opposed to replacing it completely.

You would use it like:

```
<div data-bind="templateWithContext: { name: 'TemplateName', context: { foo: 1 } }">
```

with your template like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateName">
    <input type="button" value="val" data-bind="click: $root.stop.bind($data, foo() )"/>
</script>
```